# How to join a ContentResolver Cursor with a Database Cursor?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentresolver

I get records from the system by quering a ContentResolver. I maintain the order of the items in the database. So I want to display the items in the order taken from my database.

How do I merge these two informations?

**EDIT 1**

I am looking after an alternative way now. As what I ideally want is:

- get order of contacts by a custom order held in my database (this involves joining CR with my DB cursor, and doing an order by, later seams it's not possible with CursorJoiner)
- but there is more, if the join is not unique I want to sort by contact's name as last measure

which is impossible using Cursor and Joiners, because of the missing feature of order bys, also I need to return a Cursor, as I will be using the in an ExpandableList

Also this translated to TSQL it would look like

```
select * from contactsdata 
left join category on contactsdata.catid=category.id
order by category.pos asc, contact.display_name asc
```

So I am looking now after an alternative.
I have in mind to load in a temporary DB table all data from CR, then do the query on the temporary table where I can join tables and do order bys? How does this sound to you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [`CursorJoiner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html).

If that doesn't work, you can roll your own equivalent with a fair amount of pain, whiskey, or both.

Comment: Nah, that's just the whiskey talking. :-) More seriously, I *have* rolled my own, and it's a fair bit of code to sling. It's certainly doable, but not the sort of thing you want to do if you can avoid it.

Comment: Check my edit to the original question, and my approach to load all CR data into a temporary table to run query on it.

Comment: I think your data model is waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay too complicated for a mobile device. :-) Beyond that, though, your only options are the one you described or doing all the join operations yourself in Java (e.g., to populate a `MatrixCursor`).

Comment: OK will see what I can do. Unfortunately I know the modal is too complicated, but also doesn't stop at this level. I am doing some augmented/multi-level sort order and kinda hard to put it together with CR.